# Why does learning rate reduce train-test generalization gap?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, generalization, learning-rate

In this blog post: http://www.argmin.net/2016/04/18/bottoming-out/

Prof Recht shows two plots:

[image]

[image]

He says one of the reasons the plot below has a lower train-test gap is because that model was trained with a lower learning rate (and he also manually drops the learning rate at 120 epoch).

Why would a lower learning rate reduce overfitting?

Comment: bigger learning rate makes the loss curve oscillation high, and it works for training data only

Comment: BTW, two represented figures have not the same y-scale and it can be confusing and deceptive!